# Generic solution to towers of Hanoi with variable number of poles?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, puzzle

Given D discs, P poles, and the initial starting positions for the disks, and the required final destination for the poles, how can we write a generic solution to the problem?

For example,

Given D=6 and P=4, and the initial starting position looks like this:

```
5     1
6 2 4 3
```

Where the number represents the disk's radius, the poles are numbered 1-4 left-right, and we want to stack all the disks on pole 1.

**How do we choose the next move?**

The solution is (worked out by hand):

```
3 1
4 3
4 1
2 1
3 1
```

(format: `<from-pole> <to-pole>`)

The first move is obvious, move the "4" on top of the "5" because that its required position in the final solution.

Next, we probably want to move the next largest number, which would be the "3". But first we have to unbury it, which means we should move the "1" next. But how do we decide where to place it?

That's as far as I've gotten. I could write a recursive algorithm that tries all possible places, but I'm not sure if that's optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't.

More precisely, as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Four_pegs_and_beyond says, for 4+ pegs, proving what the optimal solution is is an open problem.  There is a known very good algorithm, that is widely believed to be optimal, for the simple case where the pile of disks is on one peg and you want to transfer the whole pile to another.  However we do not have an algorithm, or even a known heuristic, for an arbitrary starting position.

If we did have a proposed algorithm, then the open problem would presumably be much easier.

Comment: It's not exactly that we can't... It's more that we don't have a efficient algorithm for it. For a reasonable number of poles/discs, a breadth-first search algorithm will work.

Comment: Took me 5 or 6 hours to come up with a solution, and it only works for a small number of disks and pegs. Wish I knew this before going into the problem :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its not that can't, its just that no one knows.